# How do i make so datetimepicker picks the time the user set to deploy local notification?

Tags: react-native

how can i manage to make so datetimepicker picks the time that the users has set to fire local shedule notifications?

This is how far ive come so far but when i press ok when selected time and date the notifications fires directley and not on the time ive set it to.

date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000) // in 60 secs <<

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
import DateTimePickerModal from "react-native-modal-datetime-picker";
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';

const DateTimePicker = () => {
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisibility] = useState(false);

  const showDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(true);
  };

  const hideDatePicker = () => {
    setDatePickerVisibility(false);
  };

  const Notification = () => {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onRegister: function(token) {
        console.log("TOKEN:", token);
      },

      onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);
      },

      permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
      },

      popInitialNotification: true,
      requestPermissions: true
    });
  }

  const SheduledNotification = date => {
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      //... You can use all the options from localNotifications
      id: '0',
      repeatType: 'day', // (optional) Repeating interval. Check 'Repeating Notifications' section for more info.
      largeIcon: "ic_launcher", // (optional) default: "ic_launcher"
      smallIcon: "ic_notification", // (optional) default: "ic_notification" with fallback for "ic_launcher"
      message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
     date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000) // in 60 secs 
    });
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Fontisto style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}} name='date' size={30} color='#000' onPress={showDatePicker} />
      <DateTimePickerModal
        isVisible={isDatePickerVisible}
        mode="datetime"
        onConfirm={SheduledNotification}
        onCancel={hideDatePicker}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default DateTimePicker;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `date` directly without `new Date()...`

Comment: Wow cant believe i never thought about that. It works by just adding date instead of new Date()............

Answer (score 0):

Did you updated your **AndroidManifest.xml**?

You have to add this line:

```
<application>
    ...

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
<application/>
```